# No Explicit General Solution to DE: Does This Case Mean That There Is No Unique Solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let's say I solve the exact differential equation

$(3x^2y + 3y^2 - 1) \ dx + (x^2 + 6xy) \ dy = 0$

and find the implicit general solution to be

$x^3y + 3xy^2 - x = C$.

Obviously, if I tried to solve this for $y$, we would have $2$ values due to the $y^2$ ($\pm$). In these cases, my instructor says that we **cannot find an explicit solution**. Is this equivalent to saying that **we cannot find a unique solution**? It seems to me like it would be, since an explicit solution would need to be of the form $y = \dots$, but in this case we have $2$ values -- $y = \pm \dots$ So it seems to me like we wouldn't have *an* explicit solution, per say, but explicit *solutions*, which, in other words, is saying that we cannot find *an* explicit solution, since there is no *unique* explicit solution?

Am I correct here, or am I getting this wrong?

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this.

Comment: I suspect the two are not equivalent. Take, for instance, the DE $$y\ dy+x\ dx=0$$ which generates concentric circles. None of them can be expressed explicitly as a function of $x$, but they are certainly unique.

Comment: @Kajelad Ahh, I suspect you're right. Perhaps the reason is just because expressing the explicit solution as $y = \pm \dots$ becomes too messy for a lot of solutions.